# PHP IIS run script as different user

Tags: php, iis, command-line-interface

I am running PHP on an older IIS 5.1 box.

I am trying to make a basic web page to check windows printer queues using the dos command "net print \pserver\printer".  If I run the command in normal cli it works great.  If trying to run it via PHP script I just get a blank page.  If I run ping command via PHP script I get output.  It seems to be a permissions problem, but I am not sure how to run this script of command as a different users.  All guides I find seems to be for linux or apache.

```
<?php

//$line = shell_exec('ping 8.8.8.8');
$line = shell_exec('net print \\pserver\printer');
echo "<pre>$line</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Check this link [Installing PHP on Windows with IIS 5.1 and 6.0](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php)

Comment: PHP is already installed and working, I am having problems running this one script.

Comment: Is there any error, have you enabled user friendly errors on IE (somewhere within the Tools->Options on the menu)

Comment: IE shows no error.  I enabled PHP errors also nothing.